# Conditionally show blocks in layout XML

Tags: layout, template, configuration, magento-1, xml

I want to **display 3 or more type of footer in my theme, but the condition via XML not working properly**. If i select Footer Default ( condition 0 ) don't show anything, if i select Footer Type 1 ( condition 1 ) i see Footer Type 1. But if is select Footer Type 2, Footer Type 3, etc i see only Footer Type 1. The "condition" work only for 0 and 1, or for all value ( 0,1,2,3,4,etc ) ?

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="footer/footer_type" condition="0">
   <template>page/html/footer/footer_type_default.phtml</template>
</action>
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="footer/footer_type" condition="1">
   <template>page/html/footer_type_1.phtml</template>
</action>
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="footer/footer_type" condition="2">
   <template>page/html/footer_type_2.phtml</template>
</action>
```

New Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

    class ThemeAdmin_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
    {
        public function getTemplate()
            {
                $footerType = Mage::getStoreConfig('footer/footer_type');
                switch ($footerType) {
                    case 0:
                        return "page/html/footer_tp_1.phtml";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        return "page/html/footer_tp_2.phtml";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        return "page/html/footer_tp_3.phtml";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }


    }
```

System.xml

```
<config>
    <tabs>
        <admin translate="label">
            <label>Admin Theme</label>
            <sort_order>00</sort_order>
        </admin>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <themeadmin translate="label">
            <label>Theme Admin</label>
            <tab>Admin</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

            <groups>

                    <footer translate="label" module="themeadmin">
                        <label>Footer</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>02</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <fields>

                            <footer_type translate="label">
                                <label>Footer Type</label>
                                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                <source_model>themeadmin/system_config_source_footer_select</source_model>
                                <sort_order>01</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            </footer_type>
                        <fields>
                   </footer>
             </groups>
        </themeadmin>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Config.xml :

```
<helpers>
    <themeadmin>
        <class>Admin_ThemeAdmin_Helper</class>
    </themeadmin>
</helpers>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ifconfig` statement only works with yes/no configuration fields.

On top of that I'm not aware of any `condition` statement to overcome the issue.

Here's the alternative:

```
<action method="setTemplate">
    <template helper="themeadmin/getTemplate"/>
</action>
```

In your module, create `Helper/Data.php` if not already created and add the following method:

```
public function getTemplate()
{
    $footerType = Mage::getStoreConfig('themeadmin/footer/footer_type');
    switch ($footerType) {
        case 0:
            return "page/html/footer/footer_type_default.phtml";
            break;
        case 1:
            return "page/html/footer_type_1.phtml";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "page/html/footer_type_2.phtml";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry not work, i see this on frontend :

Comment: @user3309614 works fine for me, please post your `system.xml`

Comment: edited, new Helper/Data.php and System.xml

Comment: @user3309614 post the full `system.xml` please, some tags are missing here. Please also post your helper definition under `config.xml`

Comment: @user3309614 I've updated my solution so it'll work with your module